# Listening comprehension (Weisst Du, was ein Schneemann träumt)

Tags: listening-comprehension

Could anyone tell me the lyrics of this German song?

This music sounds good to me but can't understand much.

I'm a beginner but to do my home work, I tried writing it down as it sounds to me.
I know there should be too many erros.. but bear with me..

```
Weisst Du, was ein Schneemann träumt Schneemann träumt Schneemann träumt
in den Winter Tage, Wollen wir ihm mal fragen.
Wenn bei uns die Sonnen scheint Sonnen  sheint Sonnen  sheint
(Heute das is klar )?? bestimmt on Kanada?   <== ???   

Guten Morgen bei den Eskimos 
Mochte er dann gerne sein   <== ???   
guckte der Hymmel noch seit beste Freund?  <== ???
und das is nur der forst allein   <=== ???
ja ja ja

...

Als ich Morgen aus dem Fenster sah,
Lock sein .
Unser Schneemann ist in kanada
Dort is es kalt doch ist ihm gut.
ja ja ja

....
```

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mKKeghWxEro&list=PLCCv7Z4W19rr3ms077O4jSKKEbjBKSiDp&index=17

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Weißt Du, was ein Schneemann träumt, Schneemann träumt, Schneemann träumt,
in den Wintertagen, wollen wir ihn mal fragen?
Wenn bei uns die Sonne scheint, Sonne scheint, Sonne scheint,
träumt er, das ist klar, bestimmt von Kanada.

Hoch im Norden bei den Eskimos, 
möchte er dann gerne sein.
Dort ist immer noch sein bester Freund,
und das ist nur der Frost allein.

Als ich morgens aus dem Fenster sah,
lag da sein Zylinderhut.
Unser Schneemann ist in Kanada,
dort ist es kalt, dort geht's ihm gut.
```

Comment: I like the tune and lyrics. It's kind of sad though. Danke sehr!

Comment: Janka, There is `und` omitted. `und das ist nur der Frost allein`.

Comment: And one *ihm* where it must read *ihn*.